# How to set a member pointer to a pointer to a data from another object?

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

I have a data parser class that will take data from a source and store it in a maprawdata. This parser class will only return a pointer to this raw data.

I have another class that will need to take this rawdata and process it again depending on an algorithm selected by the user. it has a member that is a pointer to the raw data, since I do not want to create another copy of the raw data and also protect the parsed data from any modification that might happen in the DataProcessorClass.

Parser Class:

```
class Parser
{
    public:
        map<unsigned, unsigned>* getRawdata() return { &rawdata; }
    private:
        map<unsigned, unsigned> rawdata;
};
```

DataProcessor Class:

```
class DataProcessor
{
    public:
        setRawData(map<unsigned,unsigned>* const rawdataptr) { rawdata_ptr =  rawdataptr;}
    private:
        map<unsigned, unsigned>* rawdata_ptr;
};
```

When I use this implementation, I can get the size() of the map but when I try to assign the map iterator, I get segmentation fault error:

```
void DataProcessor::ProcessDataForType1Algorithm()
{
    (*rawdata_ptr).size(); // working okay, returns the size of the map

    map<unsigned,unsigned>::iterator Itr = (*rawdata_ptr).begin(); // error segmentation fault
}
```

in main:

```
// create an object Parser
Parser Data1 = Parser("/u/server/productiondata","datafile.data");

DataProcessor *ProcessorD1 = new DataProcessor();
ProcessorD1->setRawData(Data1.getRawdata());
ProcessorD1->ProcessDataForType1Algorithm(); // <-- segfault occurs here
```

Comment: You clearly have an object lifetime issue here. And you should avoid raw pointers in C++ (pass references instead). In this case however I believe you are perfectly fine passing the map data by value (C++ has optimization for passing containers by value when no copies are needed).

Comment: It's nearly impossible to point out what is happening specifically unless you share more code, but the more or less obvious part is that your pointer lifetime is ended before you try to access it in you processor class and it's an undefined behaviour. When you have UB, you can't predict what will happen exactly, in your case, `size()` giving you a result and `begin()` crashes, there is no guaranty though.

Comment: Voting to close due to need for a [mcve].   You've shown the code that you say is crashing.   You haven't shown code with a `Parser` object, or the code that obtains a pointer from that `Parser` object. Only a guess is possible, since you haven't provided enough information, but it is likely the `Parser` object ceases to exist before `DataProcessor::ProcessDataForType1Algorithm()` is called, which cases `rawdata_ptr` to be a dangling reference (a pointer to an object that no longer exists). When a `Parser` ceases to exist, so does the map it contains - and any pointers to that map then dangle.

Comment: please include a [mcve]. The actual cause for the segfault is in code you dont show

Comment: Aside: If you are going to give everyone access to `Parser::rawdata` through `Parser::getRawData`, you may as well make it public

Comment: @ArneJ thanks for the comment. Makes sense, so I am now trying to find the lifetime of my Parser object or the lifetime of the pointer. The object has not yet been destroyed during the time the Dataprocessor accesses it...

Comment: @Peter thanks for taking time to read. There, I updated the code to demonstrate where the segfault happens.

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 I have already traced the line that is causing the segfault and shown it here. it's in the method DataProcessor::ProcessDataForType1Algorithm().

Comment: this is where you access an pointer that is most likely dangling, what makes it a dangling pointer is not possible to see in the code you posted. No need to argue, without a [mcve] we cannot know what is wrong in your code

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 can I send files over to you? I can't post it publicly. Thanks

Comment: you could but I dont want that ;). Why cant you post it publicly? MCVE stands for "minimal complete verifiable example" not for "the exact same code including confidentail information".